# How can I update a MYSQL entry automatically when a session ends?

Tags: php, mysql, session, sql-update

I have a php/html form connected to a database where users book tickets.

When a user selects a ticket it makes it unavailable, and if the user cancels the session within the browser, part of the session destroy is restoring the ticket back to the database.

However I see a potential problem with this, if the user ends the session by closing the browser tab the code to restore the ticket to the database isn't executed, and it will remain unavailable unless it is manually restored.

I'm at a loss for how to solve this, unless there is timed code that is stored on the server with php that executes in whatever manner the session ends?

I can't see another way of holding the ticket either, if the ticket isn't made unavailable someone could potentially buy it after someone else has selected it.

Comment: `unless there is timed code that is stored on the server with php that executes in whatever manner`...yep. you need a Cron job to clear up any data where the tickets have been held for too long and not purchased. It simply needs to look for any which have been held longer than your session timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use websocket connection to detect if user close tab.
2. you can add expiration date to tickets.And add a cron command to restore tickets.